# Netem on Windows?

Tags: windows, networking, emulator

I want to use a Network emulator in a Windows environment, will Netem work? If not, are there any alternatives?

Answer (score 2):

No, Netem is a Linux system. It won't work on Windows.

However, what you can do is install Netem ona linux box and use that as a router - you get better results as you're not affecting your Windows machines at all, but the netem appliance is restricting your network traffic just like you'd get in a real WAN environment.

Alternatively, use [wanem](http://wanem.sourceforge.net/) which is a livecd (so self-contained and easy to set up) of a netem-style network emulator.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a hand full of links for network emulators:

- http://packetstorm.com/psc/psc.nsf/site/2600E-software
- http://wanem.sourceforge.net/
- http://www.gns3.net/
- http://www.itrinegy.com/index.php/products/network-emulators

Answer (score -4):

If by network emulator you mean a piece of software that allows you to telnet, or ssh then I recommend you look at [PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/).